# 2 columns, one side fluid , one side fixed

Tags: html, css

Ok, so i thought this was easy as 123. I've research here and tried a couple of solutions. For some reason, i can't get it right.

Basically, i'm trying to do a layout where the left column is fluid and the right column is fixed.

HTML:

```
<div class="column-ab">
    <div class="col-content">content section</div>
    <div class="col-aside">side section</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.column-ab {background-color: black; width: 100%;}
.column-ab .col-aside, .column-ab .col-content {float: left;}
.column-ab .col-content {background-color: cyan; margin-right: 300px;}
.column-ab .col-aside {background-color: yellow; width: 300px;}
.column-ab:after {display: table; content: ""; clear: both;} /* clear */
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ud1frxdp/

Why something so easy doesn't work?

Comment: by meaning of fixed, where do you want it fixed? right? or overlapping

Comment: how old version of browser do you need to cover? .. or the latest one's only with a fallback to non-flex capable one's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn your classes into ids or they will both inherit a width of 100%; then set the width.

```css
.column-ab {background-color: black; width: 100%;}
#col-aside,  #col-content {float: left;}
#col-content {background-color: cyan; width: calc(100% - 300px);}
#col-aside {background-color: yellow; width: 300px;}
.column-ab:after {display: table; content: ""; clear: both;} /* clear */
```

```html
<div class="column-ab">
 <div id="col-content">content section</div>
 <div id="col-aside">side section</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using ID in CSS is not very recommended

Comment: @romuleald why? they are only used once?

Comment: But if not? Code reuse is important!

Comment: Which inheritance are you talking about?

Comment: never heard about the calc functionality. I've played with it and changed the css so i can still use classes.

Comment: @romuleald what is that link supposed to show? it's just a list of properties?

Comment: It shows what is inherited or not, width aren't inherited.

Comment: "Every element in an HTML document will inherit all inheritable properties from its parent except the root element (html), which doesn’t have a parent." http://www.w3.org/wiki/Inheritance_and_cascade

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution your problem can also be solved using few lines of flexbox layout. *Code explanation in comments.*

```css
.column-ab {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Wrap the divs when width is too small i.e. <300px of viewport */
}
.col-content {
  flex: 1; /* Expands and shrinks according to width, fluid content */
  background: tomato;
}
.col-aside {
  flex: 0 0 300px; /* flex-basis: 300px for fixed width */
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-ab">
  <div class="col-content">content section</div>
  <div class="col-aside">side section</div>
</div>
```

[**Updated JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ud1frxdp/1/)

Comment: This is the best solution (yet), think like this: 'I need a flexible row with a flexed child column and a fixed child column'. This will lead to a display:flex row,  left child flex:1 and right child width:300px.

Answer (score 1):

Using `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` is a common use and also a wide cross-browser code, compatibility from IE8 http://caniuse.com/#search=table

https://jsfiddle.net/ud1frxdp/3/

```
.column-ab {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.column-ab .col-aside, .column-ab .col-content {
    display: table-cell;
}
.column-ab .col-content {
    background-color: cyan;
}
.column-ab .col-aside {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 300px;
}
```

I also exploded your **CSS** because of readability, you should avoid coding like this and use a *post-processor* to minify it, being able to read the code is very important.